# 403 Forbidden when trying to register receiver endpoint using the RISC API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, secevents

While trying to register my receiver endpoint in order to start receiving RISC indications from google, I constantly get the same reply:

> 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:
> https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update

I have created the service with the Editor Role and using the json key I created as requested on the integration guide.

This is my provisioning code I use to do that:

```
import json
import time
import jwt  # pip install pyjwt
import requests


def make_bearer_token(credentials_file):
    with open(credentials_file) as service_json:
        service_account = json.load(service_json)
        issuer = service_account['client_email']
        subject = service_account['client_email']
        private_key_id = service_account['private_key_id']
        private_key = service_account['private_key']
    issued_at = int(time.time())
    expires_at = issued_at + 3600
    payload = {'iss': issuer,
           'sub': subject,
           'aud': 'https://risc.googleapis.com/google.identity.risc.v1beta.RiscManagementService',
           'iat': issued_at,
           'exp': expires_at}
    encoded = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='RS256',
                     headers={'kid': private_key_id})
    return encoded

def configure_event_stream(auth_token, receiver_endpoint, events_requested):
    stream_update_endpoint = 'https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(auth_token)}
    stream_cfg = {'delivery': {'delivery_method': 'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/delivery-method/push',
                               'url': receiver_endpoint},
                  'events_requested': events_requested}
    response = requests.post(stream_update_endpoint, json=stream_cfg, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception for unsuccessful requests


def main():
    auth_token = make_bearer_token('service_creds.json')
    configure_event_stream(auth_token, 'https://MY-ENDPOINT.io',
                       ['https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/sessions-revoked',
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/oauth/event-type/tokens-revoked',
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-disabled',
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-enabled',
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-purged',
                        'https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/account-credential-change-required'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also tested my auth token and it seems as the integration guide suggests.
Could not find 403 forbidden on the error code reference table there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for error description in the response body and match that against the possible reasons listed [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#error_codes)!